# wget mirroring the site fails - 403 Forbidden, even with user-agent

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, wget, mirroring, suricata

I need to download suricata's latest rules from this url:

http://rules.emergingthreats.net/blockrules/

I'm trying to compose my own rules based on different emerging rules and snort's rules too. Trying to replace `alert` with `drop`.

I can't even download all rules, because apache 2.2.22 of `rules.emergingthreats.net` configured somehow against `wget`.

My command looks like:

```
# wget -m --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/6.0.472.63 Safari/534.3"  "https://rules.emergingthreats.net/"
```

I'm trying to mirror whole the site.

```
--2014-07-22 06:18:49--  https://rules.emergingthreats.net/
Resolving rules.emergingthreats.net (rules.emergingthreats.net)... 204.12.217.19, 96.43.137.99
Connecting to rules.emergingthreats.net (rules.emergingthreats.net)|204.12.217.19|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘rules.emergingthreats.net/index.html’

    [ <=>                                                                                                                                                                    ] 1,951       --.-K/s   in 0s      

Last-modified header missing -- time-stamps turned off.
2014-07-22 06:18:50 (23.3 MB/s) - ‘rules.emergingthreats.net/index.html’ saved [1951]
```

Thereafter, all inner directories give me `403 Forbidden`:

```
--2014-07-22 06:18:51--  https://rules.emergingthreats.net/blockrules/
Reusing existing connection to rules.emergingthreats.net:443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2014-07-22 06:18:51 ERROR 403: Forbidden.
```

I'm successfully browse the site(directory), I can download any file with my browser - chromium ( Ubuntu ).

Why does `wget` fail to fetch the data?

Comment: ERROR 403 may also occur when checking timestamps with **`wget -N`**. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62176110/658497

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
wget -mk -w 20 --user-agent="Mozilla/4.5 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US)" https://rules.emergingthreats.net
```

The site may not know newer browser spec and you had the site url within quotes

Comment: Works. Ho do you know?

Comment: I've put -w 30, tomorrow it must be ready. Thank you.